# ErrorInternalServerError while retrieving meetings

Tags: .net, sdk, office365

In certain accounts, I receive a Object reference not set to an instance of an object whenever I try to retrieve them from the server.

One thing I notice about this accounts, is that whenever I try to edit the meetings on Office365's OWA, the page always shows blank.

The exact internal error is this

{"error":{"code":"ErrorInternalServerError","message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}}

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like the meetings are corrupted somehow. How were they created? What API are you using to retrieve them?

Comment: Im using the Office365 client SDK on WinForms.

Comment: UPDATE

IT seems that the problem was a corrupted meetings. We deleted the series and now we are able to query the Events from the Calendar. 
But the problem is still up there. How to identify or filter that sort of corrupted meetings

Comment: Do you still have the meeting? You said you deleted it, but can you get it back from deleted items? If you can, and it reproduces the error, I would then try saving the meeting to a PST file, then importing it into another mailbox to see if it reproduces. The idea is that if we can extract the "bad" meeting and retain the "bad" state, then you can work with our developer support folks to investigate further.

Comment: Id tried to restore the meeting but now it appears as cancelled :( Ill try to "enable it" and show it again in the calendar...